# Class Member Pointer Of Template Type

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class `Holder` which is template.

```
template<typename T>
class Holder {
     public:
        Holder() = default;
        ~Holder() = default;                        
        
        void Add(T &to_hold) {
            db.emplace_back(std::move(to_hold));
        }
        
     private:
        vector<T> db;
}
```

I have another class `SomeClass` that uses `Holder`:

```
class SomeClass {
    public:
      template<typename T>
      SomeClass() {
       holder_ptr = make_unique<Holder<T>>();
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }

      template<typename T>
      DoSomething(T &x) const {
         holder_ptr->Add(x);
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }
     
     private:
       template<typename T>
       unique_ptr<Holder<T>> holder_ptr;
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Im aware to the fact that the pointer `SomeClass::holder_ptr` cannot be of type `template` since at compile time, the compiler does not know the actual type of that pointer.

> Member 'holder_ptr' declared as a template

The vector `db` cannot be located as a member of `SomeClass` since `DoSomething` has to be `const`. hence `db` cannot be modified.

Need advice for solving this problem in efficient \ elegant way so the code will remain as much global as it can.

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO the question smells XY-problem.

Comment: You might want to learn the keyword `mutable`.

Comment: If you move contents out of a parameter with in `Add` I strongly recommend accepting an r-value reference, otherwise it is less obvious that the function might potentially leave the object in an unusable state. You might add an overload accepting a `const` reference as well.

Comment: Agree pretty much on the XY-problem. `doSomething` shall be `const`, but *does* modify its object? There's something going wrong!

Comment: `template<typename T> SomeClass()` You cannot invoke this constructor so `SomeClass` objects cannot exist at all, regardless of how or whether `holder_ptr` is defined. Perhaps you need `template<typename T> class SomeClass()` and no template members inside, as the answer suggests. Perhaps you need something else. It depends on how you want to use `SomeClass`. Can you give some examples?

Comment: Then again even *if* the other code *did* work (without making the class itself a template) then `template<typename T> doSomething(T &x) const { holder_ptr->add(x); }`  wouldn't work either as the `T` coming from the member variable and the `T` of the function aren't necessarily the same... You would need to add a type check, most likely with `Holder` class having some kind of `using value_type = T;` declaration.

Comment: Making `SomeClass` a template might be an option, though you couldn't have them e.g. stored within the same container. You might get around that problem with a common base class then, though, and manage them polymorphically then. Or you have a polymorphic `Holder` class (non-template base, templated derived). For the problem with the constructor you might create a `Tag` class/struct such that you could create your class via `SomeClass instance(Tag<int>());` – doable. Convenient? Depends...

Comment: As the suspicion of an XY-problem arose already you might want to describe what you actually want to *do* with this class. There might be better options!